# Bootstrap-select multiselect appearing weirdly

Tags: html, css, select, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I am trying to add a multi-select dropdown in one of the projects. I'm using the bootstrap-select library for this. While it works fine on my other project, it is not working as expected in this one. Here's the screenshot of how it is appearing--
[image]

while it is supposed to appear like this -
[image]

---

Here's the code-

```
<label for="employees">Employee(s) &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
 <select id="employees" class="form-control select" multiple="true" style="width: 300px;">
 <option value="SPM">SPM</option>
 <option value="SPM">Hello</option>
 <option value="SPM">World</option>
 </select><input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//$("#old-proj").multiselect();
$("#employees").multiselect();
});
```

Please help with the issue, if you understand this. Thanking in anticipation. Regards

Comment: is this project online? if yes can you share link . there could be some custom css that is getting applied on this.

Comment: Actually, mutliselect has been implemented in this project on other pages and I'm supposed to add this on the new one but I'm unable to figure out what's the first thing I should do as it's a large project. 
Any suggestions?